# AppleScript: How to identify checkbox location in System Preferences?

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to issue a keyboard command to toggle the checkbox "Change picture every 30 minutes" in `OS X` for `Desktop 1` (my main monitor desktop). I have multiple monitors so it may be necessary to identify which particular preference pane to manipulate.

I have set up the start of an AppleScript, but I'm at a loss how to formulate how to identify this particular check box:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click menu item "Desktop & Screen Saver" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    delay 2
    tell window "Desktop & Screen Saver"
        click checkbox 1 of …
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `tab group 1`. You can recognize this with the help of the Xcode tool Accessibility Inspector (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector in the menu bar or Dock).

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect"
end tell

delay 2

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox "Change picture:" of tab group 1 of window "Desktop & Screen Saver"
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I will install XCode.